# Express API "Create User" operation fires early with undefined values, without waiting for Mongoose Query Middleware to configure those values

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, promise

I have built a Registration form where there are two Client Usertypes - Master and Child. Master users have their own Database space built out for them using a specific access key.

When a user registers as a Child account, the API has some Middleware make a query for a Master account to bind to and retrieve this Access Key, which is a required field in the Mongoose Schema.

My issue is that - occasionally the middleware will be skipped entirely - or more accurately, it will not actually WAIT for the Query callback to complete, and will immediately fire off `next()` without awaiting the result of the mongoose query.

This results in a 500 Error since a required Mongoose Schema field has not been retrieved, and the registration process aborts.

Here is the API code and CRUD route:

```
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

router.route('/clients')
    .post(register.configureNewUser, clients.createClient);
```

**MIDDLEWARE:** *register.configureNewUser:*

```
module.exports.configureNewUser = function(req, res, next) {

    if (req.body.isEmployee) {
        req.body.isMaster = false;
        findMasterAndTagChild(req, res, next) // Middleware which needs to run for successful registration  
    }
}
```

**Subsequent Middleware: (This is the one that is being skipped over before it gets a chance to complete!!):**

```
findMasterAndTagChild = function(req, res, next) {
    Client.findOne({
        isMaster: true,
        organizationName: req.body.employerLookup
    }, 
            function(err, boss) {
                if (err) return next(err);
                req.body.mongoCollectionKey = boss.mongoCollectionKey; // req.body.mongoCollectionKey is undefined in clients.createClient
                req.body.organizationName = boss.organizationName;
            }).exec().then(() => next()) // next() fires before all code in query callback completes 
}
```

I believe I am using promises incorrectly here. I understand that Mongoose Queries are not Promises, but why is my `.then()` firing before the Mongoose Query Callback gets a chance to execute all of its code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are using both a callback function and promises. You need to move the callback functionality into the `.then` callback:

```
.then(boss => {
  req.body.mongoCollectionKey = boss.mongoCollectionKey;
  req.body.organizationName = boss.organizationName;
  next();
}).catch(err => next(err));
```

If you're able to use `async`/`await` you can write this a bit more cleanly:

```
findMasterAndTagChild = async function(req, res, next) {
  try {
    const boss = await Client.findOne({
      isMaster: true,
      organizationName: req.body.employerLookup
    }); 
    req.body.mongoCollectionKey = boss.mongoCollectionKey;
    req.body.organizationName = boss.organizationName;
    next();
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the help! I was just jamming in `.exec()` and `.then()` all over, wondering why my functions that relied on several different queries were not working. I will definitely have to look into `async`/`await`. Is there any kind of improvement in functionality/versatility when using `async`/`await` as opposed to `then`, or is it more of a readability thing?

Comment: @Mikhail mostly readability. I wrote a blog post about it actually: https://medium.com/@ExplosionPills/sinking-your-teeth-into-async-await-ce46203b4f98

Comment: Awesome, thanks again for the help! Saved me from an all-day headache :D